# How can I get an express server to send the data retrieved by a separate provider to a client?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently writing a small program in Node.js for an express server. I am using providers to facilitate the separation of concerns. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to send a return value from the provider function back to the express server and then to the client. I'm probably missing something with the asynchronous code but can't seem to figure out what. I'd be grateful if you could guide me in the right direction! Sorry if this is an obvious question, I'm very new to programming.

This is the code skeleton for the main.js:

```
server.get("/someurl*", (req, res) => {
    let name = req.query.name;
    let id = req.query.id;
    if (
        (isValid(name) == true) &&
        (isValid(id) == true)
    ) {
        let provider = new getSomething();
        provider.getMethod(id);
        res.send(provider.getMethod(id));
    };
});
```

This is the code skeleton for provider.js:

```
class getSomething extends abstractClass {
     getMethod(id) {
         this.id = id;
         // Acquiring data from database based on id
         …
         if (err)
             return (‘error’);
         return data;
     };
};
```

What I do not understand is how can I send the data back to the express server (main.js) and then send that data back to the client with `res.send`. The way I'm doing it above doesn't work as it returns an undefined value. I cannot do `res.send` directly from the provider as it should only be responsible for retrieving data from the database and the server instance is defined in main.js.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your provider class I would ammend the getMethod to be something more like this:

```
getMethod(id) {
    this.id = id;
    //do something. update this.data
    if (err) this.error = err;
    //optional for method chaining: return this;
}
```

Class methods can be used to modify the properties of the class, which you can then send to the client.

then in your endpoint:

```
server.get(“/someurl*”, (req, res) => {
    const name = req.query.name; //use consts for values that you dont want to change
    const id = req.query.id;

    if ((isValid(name) == true) && (isValid(id) == true)) {
         const provider = new getSomething();
         provider.getMethod(id);
         if (provider.error) return res.status(500).json({error: provider.error});
         return res.status(200).json({data: provider.data});

    };
    return res.status(500).error({error: 'query data not valid'});
});
```

this is extracting the data you require from the query object, then if everything is valid (im asuming some other function you have for validation) will instantiate a new instance of your class, run the method, and if theres an error send this back to the client otherwise send back data to the client.

If the data is not valid it also sends back a response to the client. In any case you want to send something back to the client.

Comment: Thanks Richard! This has helped me to understand the logic better - thank you for taking time to writing notes! My provider still seems to send me an undefined response - does it have anything to do with the fact that my response is a string (it has to be)?

Comment: What method are your using to get the data? perhaps you are doing something asyncronously so its sending to the client before the data is available? can you share your provider code that is getting the data?

Comment: I just found out that the in-memory store I was using to get the data doesn't have return implemented and, instead, needs a callback from the main script. The in-memory store was levelup(memdown) - https://github.com/Level/memdown Thanks for your help!